# Which is the standard for the position of the source in figure captions?

Tags: captions, positioning

Since my university gives no rules about that, I'm following the standard caption positioning: on top for tables, bottom for figures.

For some tables/figures, I also have to give the source of them, but I don't know where to position this informations.

Is there an official journal guide which covers this topic?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% bold "table" and "figure" in caption and indentation
\usepackage[%
  font=small,
  labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,format=hang,
  ]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=above, aboveskip=4pt}%, belowskip=6pt}

% table template
\newcommand{\source}{\emph{Source}:~}
\newcommand{\tabfs}{\small}
\NewEnviron{tabnote}[1][para]{%
    \begin{tablenotes}[#1]    
        \footnotesize \BODY
    \end{tablenotes} 
}
\NewEnviron{tabella}{%
    \begin{table}[t]
        \centering\small\begin{threeparttable}
            \BODY
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
}
% figure template
\NewEnviron{figura}{%
    \noindent\begin{figure}[t]
        \centering
        \BODY
    \end{figure}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabella}
\caption{\label{tab:mylabel}My table caption with indentation if it is too long}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule 
Head 1 & Head 2\\
\midrule
Something &  1\\
Something else & 0\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabnote}
\source My source.
\end{tabnote}
\end{tabella}

\begin{figura}
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}
\caption{\label{tab:mylabel}My figure caption  with indentation if it is too long. My figure caption  with indentation if it is too long. My figure caption  with indentation if it is too long.
\source My source.}
\end{figura}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is a TeX question?

Comment: I'm unsure as well and only recall cases in which we closed these questions. Maybe you should ask in chat whether someone knows a good place to ask this kind of question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the [AMS Style Guide for journals](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/AMS-StyleGuide-online.pdf) addresses this on page 47.

In brief, the permission/credit statement is included at the end of the figure caption.
(Examples are shown to illustrate the principle.)

Table captions (addressed on page 55) are treated similarly, except for the placement of
the caption:  table captions above the table, figure captions below the figure.

This, of course, is the recommendation of one particular U.S. publisher; other publishers
may have other ideas.